# Rider: set namespace autofill as absolute namespace instead relative

Tags: c#, rider

When I'm using new class the Rider import the file by using the relative namespace, there is an option to set the Rider to use the absolute namespace instead?

for example, instead

```
using Collections.Generic;
```

autofill

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you need to check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) official page.

In project settings you can set root namespace for all your project, and all your classes will import this namespace by pattern like:

```
{root namespace}.{local namespace (such as Contracts)}.{subnamespaces and etc.}
```

For example:

If you have Project called as Castle

and interface in local namespace IContract, and you want to use Logger namespace you will see smth like this

```cs
using Castle.Logger;

namespace Castle.Contracts;

public interface IContract {}
```